# How to use a localhost API in angular

Tags: django, angular

I want to use an API running at localhost:8000/data into my angular app which is running at localhost:4200.

I am getting the below error in the browser.

[image: Browser console]

Comment: please share your code as well.

Comment: You can temporary disable CORS for dev purposes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/7415288

Comment: I do not have time to write a full answer, but this option should do the trick (and will not require you to disable CORS locally): https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server - Basically you will allow your frontend to issue the calls to `localhost:4200/api`, but have angular rewrite the outgoing call to `localhost:XXX/api` and disable CORS on the way automatically for development purposes.

Comment: Setup: https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/0.01/
And It's done.

Answer (score 1):

Its a backend "problem". The backend can use in local env:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Or you start the chrome without CORS, e.g. on mac

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```